# confusion matrix of random forest ( from Scikit- learn)

Tags: python, random-forest

I'm performing random forest classification for two classes(0 or 1), and I often get "confusion matrix" to valuate the model.

But always I'm not sure which row is for which class.
In the case, I know the numbers of each class I can tell tho.

Could you tell me the easy way to know?

Comment: I don't get the question. Could you maybe rephrase it to be more understandable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is stated in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html):

> **labels** : array, shape = [n_classes], optional
>
> List of labels to index
>   the matrix. This may be used to reorder or select a subset of labels.
>   If none is given, those that appear at least once in y_true or y_pred
>   are used in sorted order.

This means that the classes are in ascending order unless you sklearn otherwise by supplying a list of labels, e.g. `confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels=[1, 0])` would swap the classes around.

Element [0,0] is the number of correct classifications in the 0 class and element [1,1] is the number of correct classifications in the 1 class.